# How can I get this 'mask div' to overlay content without pushing it down?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to put a 'mask' over a div that contains scrollable content using CSS `position: sticky`.  I want the mask to overlay the content but *not* the scrollbar.  In addition, the container height needs to be defined using `max-height` instead of `height`.  I've almost got it to do what I want, except for the fact that it pushes the content beneath down, whereas I want the content to start at the top of the container, where it would if the sticky were not there.  I've read that this should be possible but I can't seem to get it to work right.  What am I doing wrong?

[Here's the Codepen.](https://codepen.io/jez9999/pen/ZERLoYv)

The code:

```css
div {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#stickyMask {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Below is some masked scrollable content:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div id="stickyMask">
    Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
  </div>
  <h3>
    Content which overflows and scrolls
  </h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add your code in a snippet in case the pen get changed or deleted

Comment: @Cédric Did you vote to close?  If so I'm adding the code now, please remove that vote.

Comment: use absolute instead of sticky? seems to start at the top anyway and if you don't want the content pushing down to start with, I see no reason for it to be sticky

Comment: I did not, but I would not have been surprised if the question was closed because of that, I would be a bit rude since the question was just posted and a pen was linked, but please check [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: `position: sticky` *preserves* the space a 'sticky' element originally occupies where `position: absolute` does not (`white-space` collapses). If you only need one element to be sticky, I suggest you use `position: absolute; z-index: 1` instead and make `.container` `relative`.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Could you post that as an answer with a code example please?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `fixed` instead of `absolute`, but there's something fishy going on with that. `fixed` seems always relative to the viewport/body, unless the elements ancestor has a `transform`, `perspective`, or `filter` property set to something other than `none`. I used `.container { transform: translateZ(0) }` for that purpose. Net result is that the `fixed` element (`#stickyMask`) is put inside `.container`, but now behaves like an `absolute` element, moving out of view on scroll. Likely as per W3C specs, but unexpected (by me anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add an extra wrapper you can use CSS grid like below:

```css
.container {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;

  /* Currently a bug in Firefox makes the following not work: */
  /*grid-template-rows: 100%;*/ /* height of row equal to height of container */

  /* Luckily there is an equivalent that does work cross-browser */
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr); /* height of row equal to height of container */
}

.container > * {
  grid-area: 1/1; /* both child on the same area above each other */
}

#stickyMask {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Below is some masked scrollable content:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div id="stickyMask">
    Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
      Content which overflows and scrolls
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like it achieves what I'm looking for.  I don't normally consider CSS grid as it's so complex.  Thanks!

Comment: I see you set the row height to 100%, but how come the width is 100%?  Is that the default for grid?

Comment: @Jez you will have one column with an auto width and since you have enough content it will take all the available space. Even with a smaller content, the stretch alignment will strike. I am setting 100% for the height to reduce the height. Don't think that it's to make the height bigger. Your content is bigger so I need to limit the height to only 100%

Comment: Right.  Yeah I just tried replacing all the paragraphs with "Lorem" and the width of the mask still covers the whole container so I guess it's the stretch alignment doing it.

Comment: I've just noticed this doesn't work in Firefox if container is set via `max-height`.  Argh!

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't have expected it to make a difference.  It seems like a basic bug in Firefox.

Comment: Despite the current bugs in browser rendering meaning this solution doesn't completely work cross-browser, I think it probably is the correct answer.  Semantically, according to the specs, it ought to work.

Comment: OK, I've marked this as the answer after applying a CSS fix. Your original CSS should actually work in Firefox, there's [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481876) in Firefox which prevents it from working. Luckily, the equivalent `grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);` does work!

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for? You can put the content in its own `<div>` and then use `position: absolute` with `pointer-events: none` on the mask to overlay it while making the content scrollable.

```css
div {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#stickyMask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0.5;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Below is some masked scrollable content:</h2>

<div class="container">
  
    <div id="stickyMask">
        Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
    </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <h3>
      Content which overflows and scrolls
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The trouble with that solution is that that mask overlays the scrollbar, but I only want it overlaying the content.

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the sticky does not have to be 100%, then the following works (at least on chrome on android on a mobile phone):

Set the height of the sticky to anything other than a percentage, eg, 500px, or 50vh, ...

Wrap the scrolling content in its own div and set its positon to relative with top set -500px, -50vh, ie, the negative of the height of the sticky.

(BTW Height set to 100% messed up seriously on my phone when I ran the code outside of SO's fiddler.)

[EDIT 22021113]

A possible  solution which allows for a generic mask-scroll area (height) to be defined follows:

```css
div {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    overflow: auto;
    /*  Set up generic height of mask-scroll area  */
    --max-height: 250px;
    max-height: var(--max-height);
}

#stickyMask {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*  Make the mask cover the full height  */
    min-height: var(--max-height);
}

#content {
    /*  Push the content up to the top of the sticky element  */
    position: relative;
    top: calc(0px - var(--max-height));
    /*  Trim off the space at the bottom left behind after moving the content up  */
    margin-bottom: calc(0px - var(--max-height));
}
```

```html
<h2>Below is some masked scrollable content:</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div id="stickyMask">
        Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
        Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
        Green mask using sticky positioning inside a container
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h3>Content which overflows and scrolls</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have only tested this on chrome on windows.

Comment: Yeah, I do need it to be 100%.  It's meant to be a generic mechanism for putting a mask over all of some background content which scrolls.

Comment: Note that 'height: 100%;' does not pick up the rendered height limited by max-height.  It looks back to ancestors until it finds a height set.  In this case there is none so 100% is the body height.  Relying on 100% to set the the mask height could have unwanted results depending on the context. I will add a second solution to my answer which allows a generic mask-scroll area height to be set. Hopefully, it is generic in the way you need it to be.

Comment: Interesting use of CSS variables there.  Would it be better though to set `stickyMask` `height`, with its `overflow:hidden` so prevent its content possibly overflowing and causing a scrollbar on the mask?

Comment: I do not get a second scroll bar.  Because min-height is set the mask thinks it had no over flow because the height can be as big as required as far as the mask is is concerned.  The only element specifically over flowing is the container.  It is the only element that has an upper limit on its height.  What I see is an "oversized" mask will start to scroll up with the content when the bottom of the not visible area of the longer content comes up to the bottom of the not visible area of the mask. They then scroll in synch until both are fully scrolled up  (at least on chrome on windows).

Comment: I've been looking at the [height docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) on MDN and it's interesting; you're right that `height: 100%` doesn't pick up the rendered height limited by `max-height`, though the docs imply that it does for absolutely positioned content: "If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto". That should mean that putting it in a `relative` positioned wrapper with a `max-height` and giving it 100% height works.

Comment: That does indeed seem to work fine in Chrome, but Firefox continues to give the mask div the same height as the full overflowed content of the other div, even when I put `container` in a relative-positioned wrapper and give it absolute positioning.

Comment: It is nearly midnight here and I do not know if I will be able to get back to the computer for a couple of days, and I will have to install FF.  Try adding 'height: min-content;' to the mask CSS rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249551/discussion-between-jez-and-petern0691).